# SQL- Convert varchar(8) to time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, time-format

the time is saved as varchar(8) format like: 09241324 and I want to convert it into time format. I can get rid off the last `nn` so `hh:mm:ss` would work. I tried using cast/convert but it is throwing error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Time / Date functions differ between implementations.

Comment: It is sql server 2008 R2

Comment: If at all possible you should change the datatype of the table and store time information in the time datatype. Storing this stuff in character form is a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
convert(time, stuff(stuff(stuff(dt, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, '.'))
```

`cast` is usually favored over `convert` but off the top of my head I wasn't sure whether you'd need to specify a format code.

Without milliseconds is similar:

```
convert(time, stuff(stuff(stuff(dt, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 2, '.00'))
```

Comment: Your STUFF is much cleaner than my SUBSTRING

Comment: I always have to look up the arguments on `stuff` though :)

Comment: Thanks! it works but i just want first 6 digits like hh:mm:ss and not the nanoseconds. Is there anyway to remove those?

Comment: @GeetanjaliSachdeva use `time(0)` to store only hh:mm:ss instead of `time`

Answer (score 1):

Insert the time formatting pieces ( colons : and decimal . ), and CAST as TIME:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10)
SET @string = '09241324'
SELECT CAST(
    SUBSTRING(@string,1,2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(@string,3,2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(@string,5,2) + '.' +
    SUBSTRING(@string,7,2) AS TIME)
```